# bootstrap 3 carousel caption scrolls over navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, scroll, carousel

I have used .affix to change my static-top navbar to fixed-top. All of my content, including carousel images, scroll under the navbar with the exception of the carousel-caption content. I want the carousel-caption content to scroll under the navbar too. Could the z-index be affecting this?

```
#nav.affix{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Changing the z-index to 10000 fixed it for me.